# Flex ... Need to make Cool website 

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I need to make a fantastic website for my company. It is my project. I know a bit of flex and AS, but not in depth.

1. Can anyone tell me how to make cool websites with dynamic features (using flex and AS) so that everyone will like it.  What are diff books and resources that I have to go through ?
2. Do I need to use any other technology in **integration** with Flex and AS ? What are the books & learning resources for the same ?
3. Do i need to use flash with flex ? If yes, how should i approach with it ?

Please guide me ... Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The 'cool' requirement makes it *very* subjective.

Comment: @pavium :Cool means everyone should be able to applaud my website.

Comment: I've made no moves to close the question. I hope to find out what 'cool' means in this context.

Comment: Yusuf, welcome to Stack Overflow! :) I am voting to close this question because it is _extremely_ broad. Furthermore, because it is subjective, it would be difficult to accept any specific answer as "correct" (however helpful). If this question is closed by the community, I would suggest that breaking it apart into smaller questions would drastically help -- but those might still be overly broad and subjective. Please read a [guide to what we like to see in our questions](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) for further information. On to your question: Make your website work before making it cool.

Comment: I'm afraid that I have to agree that this question should be closed. It is not well formed and while I respect the intent, it is reminiscent of a [story I read once](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Could-You-Explain-Programming-Please.aspx).

Comment: Once again the Close Nazis strike. Who cares if it's broad? Newtang managed to address his questions just fine. This guy needs information and assistance. He just asked for a few opinions on how to get started with a project (so it's slightly subjective--so what?) The spirit and purpose of this site is to provide assistance--not to follow some goofy strict doctrine of rules and regulations.  And there's nothing wrong with a little subjective brainstorming for ideas--what harm is it doing?

Comment: Why close? - question 2 & 3 were 100% answerable, and even though 1 wasn't, there's nothing wrong with asking for some good *up to date/recent* book recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell you how to make it cool, because that's extremely subjective.  It also depends entirely on what you're building (e-commerce site, game, etc).

2) Knowing a bit of HTML always helps.  However, Flash and Flash Builder can generate the necessary HTML for you.  If you're going to need a serverside component, you'll need to know a serverside language like Python, PHP, Ruby, etc.  This comes in handy for having users save configurations across sessions, storing data, connecting to other web services, authetication, etc.  You may also have to familiarize yourself with a database like MySQL to store data.  However, none of this is necessarily essential.  You can make a fun game without knowing any of this.

3) Flex is a UI framework for Flash.  You can't have Flex without Flash.

Good luck!